# MySQL Compare Rows with empty entries

Tags: mysql, self-join

I've read a lot of the examples on self join, but they don't seem to cover the case where some fields are not in some rows.

For eg, I have a database with:

```
testId, testItem, testResult
```

And the rows:

```
 1,test1,1
 1,test2,0
 1,test3,1
 2,test1,0
 2,test4,1
 2,test5,1
```

I would like the output:

```
testItem,a.testId,b.testId,a.testResult,b.testResult
test1,1,2,1,0
test2,1,NULL,0,NULL
test3,1,NULL,1,NULL
test4,NULL,2,NULL,1
test5,NULL,2,NULL,1
```

Essentially, I want to compare each testItem (test1->test5) from two different testIds (1 and 2) and compare their testResult values, factoring in testIds that may not have the same test Items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your exact requirement, you can try this:

```
select testItem
     , max(case when testID = 1 then testID else null end) as testID1
     , max(case when testID = 2 then testID else null end) as testID2
     , max(case when testID = 1 then testResult else null end) as testResult1
     , max(case when testID = 2 then testResult else null end) as testResult2
from mytable
where testID in (1,2)
group by testItem
```

This makes a lot of assumptions about your data, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: This looks like the closest to what I need, thanks! Can you share a couple of assumptions so I avoid pitfalls in expanding on this method?

Comment: The main assumption is that there will only be one "Result" for each combination of "Item" and "ID". We can't know for sure without knowing more about your data.  For example, if your table has a unique index on those two columns, we'd know for sure.  When you ask questions like this in the future, it's always a good idea to show the `CREATE TABLE` statement for tables.  That will show things like column attributes and indexes.  Otherwise, people must guess.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a FULL OUTER JOIN, which is not supported in MySQL. You can emulate this with a UNION of two queries: a LEFT JOIN query and RIGHT JOIN which throws out matching rows.

Something like this will return the specified resultset:

```
SELECT a.testItem
     , a.testId      AS `a.testId`
     , b.testId      AS `b.testId`
     , a.testResult  AS `a.testResult`
     , b.testResult  AS `b.testResult`   
  FROM mytable a
  LEFT
  JOIN mytable b
    ON b.testItem = a.testItem
       AND b.testId = 2
 WHERE a.testId = 1
   AND a.testItem IN ('test1','test2','test3','test4','test5')
 UNION ALL
SELECT d.testItem
     , c.testId
     , d.testId
     , c.testResult
     , d.testResult
 FROM mytable d
 LEFT
 JOIN mytable c
   ON c.testItem = d.testItem
      AND c.testId = 1
WHERE d.testId = 2
  AND d.testItem IN ('test1','test2','test3','test4','test5')
  AND c.testId IS NULL
ORDER
   BY 1,2,4
```

(I included the predicates on testItem IN ('test1' thru 'test5') because you specified that as a requirement; those predicates could be removed if you want all values for testItem included.)

Answer (score 0):

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19fea/17)

```
select testItem, 
group_concat(IFNULL(testId,'null') separator ', ') testIds,
group_concat(IFNULL(testResult, 'null') separator ', ') testResults
from table_name group by testItem;
```

Comment: This sort of worked for me, but everything is dumped in one column which makes it harder for parsing out.. is it possible to return it in columns like how I described above?